# wordpress - How can I display post link group by year?

Tags: wordpress

I want to display a list of post link group by year. Archive function don't do it
Eg:

```
2010
  Blender 2.53 released
  Gamequery 0.5 released
  synfig 0.62.02 released
  ...

2009
  Gimp 2.67 released
  Blender 2.52 released
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9):

Query all your posts, ordered by post date (descending I assume?). You print them one by one, remember the year, and when the year of the current post is not the same as the year of the previous post, you know you have to print a year label.

```
query_posts(array('nopaging' => 1, /* we want all posts, so disable paging. Order by date is default */));
$prev_year = null;
if ( have_posts() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post();
      $this_year = get_the_date('Y');
      if ($prev_year != $this_year) {
          // Year boundary
          if (!is_null($prev_year)) {
             // A list is already open, close it first
             echo '</ul>';
          }
          echo '<h3>' . $this_year . '</h3>';
          echo '<ul>';
      }
      echo '<li>';
      // Print the link to your post here, left as an exercise to the reader
      echo '</li>';
      $prev_year = $this_year;
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I like to add get_year_link($this_year), can be useful for others if they want to link to an archive.

Comment: }?>
          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_title() ?></a></li>
    <?php

Instead of // Print the link to your post here, left as an exercise to the reader

Comment: Use `echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';` instead of `echo '<li>';
      // Print the link to your post here, left as an exercise to the reader
      echo '</li>';` if you're writing it right in place of the other line

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I enjoyed the exercise near the end of the code - keeping us on our toes I see.  Well played, good sir.

Comment: Hi @Jan. What if we want pagination?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try the following code:

```
wp_get_archives(array('type' => 'yearly'));
```

There are several more parameters to try. Please refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives for details.

Comment: Second answer:  it's generate a archive' list link to pages, not link to post !!

Comment: Calm down please. I'm sure the wp_get_archives function generates links to posts. Please try "wp_get_archives(array('type' => 'postbypost'));"

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to make your own custom query to get the posts by year. Something like this:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE site_id = %d AND public = '1' AND archived = '0' AND mature = '0' AND spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' AND last_updated != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' group by postyear", $wpdb->siteid );
```

Note: where I put "group by postyear", I'm not sure what that column name would be, so you'd have to figure out how that's stored in your blogs table. That may be a case where you have to parse out the year from a date field. Give that a shot. Then you can format your output like this:

```
$terms = $wpdb->get_results($query,ARRAY_A);
    echo "<ul>";    
    foreach($terms as $detail)
    {
        echo "<li style='font-size:1.3em;'><a href='http://".$detail[ 'domain' ].$detail['path']."'>".get_blog_option( $detail['blog_id'], 'blogname' )."</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```