# Split WP_POSTS table based on post years

Tags: database, wordpress, split

How I can split `wordpress` posts in the database? In the dashboard I want all the posts to showup as they currently do but save to different tables.

I split the tables but my issue now is I want to save the posts to `wp_posts_2016` and `wp_posts_2017` instead of the default `wp_posts` table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397725/wordpress-how-can-i-display-post-link-group-by-year

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wordpress - How can I display post link group by year?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397725/wordpress-how-can-i-display-post-link-group-by-year)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question. The user wants to split the database tables and not the data printed to the screen.

Comment: Make the title and question clear of whats being asked.